# One DLL not finding another DLL - error 126

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I have an issue that I have been trying to resolve for several days and just can’t find the source. I have read several blogs on this issue but none of them have worked for me. There exists a question on Stack Overflow that describes my issue almost exactly.

It reads as follows:

> “I have an MFC .exe that loads a dll. The .dll is dynamically linked
>   to MFC. The error I am getting is 126, that is, after attempting to
>   load the .dll it fails and GetLastError() returns 126: "The specified
>   module could not be found". I tried placing the .dll in the directory
>   that my .exe is in that loads it - still does not find it. I even
>   tried hard coding the path to the .dll and it still does not find it.”

The response to this question was:

> “Probably, not the DLL itself, but one of its dependencies cannot be
>   found. Use Dependency Walker utility to identify all dependent DLLs.
>   It will warn you if some of dependent DLLs are missing.”

The programmer asking the question was able to resolve the problem based on that but I have not been so fortunate. I am out of ideas and hoping that someone can help me resolve this frustrating issue.

I am 99% sure that this is the case for me. In my case, my dll (My.dll) imports another library. I will call it Suspect.dll and Suspect.lib.

In my DLL’s Property Pages under “Linker Input” the suspect import library is included in the list and the path is correct:  Suspect.lib.

When I run the app, I can see via my IDE's output window that My.dll loads but then is unloaded.

This application ran successfully in the past but I went from a VS2008 project file to a makefile using CMake and then back. I believe that some of the settings were changed in the process but I’m just not seeing it.

I am down to the wire so if someone can help me, I would GREATLY appreciate it!

Comment: What happens when you open your DLL using the DEPENDS utility?  This'll help you determine if "suspect.dll" can be resolved.

Comment: You just need another pair of eyes on this problem, better ones than Depends has.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor, you'll see exactly what it is trying to load and where it looks for the DLL.

Comment: I have also tried SetDllDirectory() and the Dependency Walker profiler but no luck.

Comment: Wow! You guys are fast!

Comment: With DEPENDS, my DLL does not show up since it is dynamically loaded.

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrectly referring to opening my executable in DEPENDS, in which case (my DLL) is not listed there because it is dynamically loaded. I will open the DLL.

Comment: Bukes: "suspect.dll" cannot be resolved.

Comment: Hans: I will try Process Monitor.

Comment: What happens when you point DEPENDS at suspect.dll?  Are all of it's imports resolved?

Comment: I ran the application through the DEPENDS profiler. As suspected, Suspect.dll is not found. In the right-hand side window, The function call that My.dll makes to Suspect.dll is listed and the Entry Point says "Not Bound".

Comment: Do you have access to the source?  Is it failing on the LoadLibrary (of your DLL), or failing on the GetProcAddr (of the function inside the DLL)?

Comment: It is failing on the Load Library. I would like to paint a bigger picture. Hopefully, I will not confuse the tar out of you folks.

Comment: Oops. I didn't mean to submit the comment yet.

Comment: I have an application and 5 dlls. The app loads 4 of the libraries using AfxLoadLibrary. They all load successfully except for the 4th library. I will call it Lib4.dll. The difference with Lib4.dll is that it imports the 5th library. The 4th library calls a function that is exported in Lib5.dll. When I launch the application, I can see (in debug windows) that Lib4.dll loads, but then unloads.

Comment: Here are the results from the Dependency Walker Profiler:  In the Dependency Tree, The icon for Lib4.dll is pink with a star burst. From DW help site, this indicates the following: (next comment ...)

Comment: "Dynamic module warning. This module is either missing one or more export functions that the parent module attempted to retrieve using GetProcAddress, is of the wrong CPU type, or failed to initialize when being loaded. For a missing export, the Parent Import Function List View will list the actual functions that the parent module could not locate. For dynamic dependencies, this is usually just a warning, since it is perfectly valid for a module to dynamically check for the existence of a function in another module, even if the function does not exist." . . .

Comment: Further, in the Dependency Tree below Lib4.dll, the dll with the exported function Lib5.dll is listed as: "Missing module. This module could not be found in the search path". . . .

Comment: Lastly (in my bigger picture thread), when I click on Lib5.dll in the tree, the Export Function List View, lists the exported function in red with an "Entry Point" as "Not Bound".

Comment: Ok, one more clue: Within my code and project settings, if I break the dependency between Lib4.dll and Lib5.dll, then Lib4.dll loads successfully.